# How to Preserve Case of Inputted Chars in C?

Tags: c, char, ascii, cs50, alphabetical

The user inputs chars that can be uppercase or lowercase. I need to spit an answer back that preserves the case of the inputted char after that char is processed by my code. How do I preserve case when the char was converted to its ASCII value and then to its alphabetical index equivalent.

Here is my code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
  int counter = 0;
  if (argc == 2) {
    for (int k = 0; k < strlen(argv[1]); k++) {
      if (isdigit(argv[1][k])) {
        counter++;
      }
    }

    if (strlen(argv[1]) == counter)
    {
      string s = get_string("plaintext: ");
      printf("ciphertext: ");

      for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++) {
        int c = (int) s[i];
        if (c >= 97 && c <= 122)
        {
          printf("%i\n", (((c % 32) - 1 + atoi(argv[1]))) % 26);
        }
        printf("\n");

        if (c >= 65 && c <= 90)
        {
          printf("%i", (((c % 32)) - 1 + atoi(argv[1])) % 26);
        }

        printf("\n");
      }

    } else {
      printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
    }
  }
}
```

Expected behavior would print Zoo as "App" if Key entered in command line were 1.

Comment: Don't use `c % 32`, that filters out the case.

Comment: Use `c - 'a'` for lowercase, and `c - 'A'` for uppercase. Also, you should use `isupper()` and `islower()` rather than hard-coding ASCII codes.

Comment: Ok so should i put c - 'a' in the "if" before print which has atoi?

Comment: If you have to manipulate the original string, why don't you simply copy it into a "placeholder" using `strcpy` ?

Comment: Don't use magic numbers. Don't expect the reader to know what `97` and `122` means. Character constants `'a'` and `'z'` are better (they're even of type `int`). Even better, don't make assumptions about the numeric values of letters; see `isupper()`, `islower()`, `toupper()`, and `tolower()` in `<ctype.h>`. C doesn't guarantee `'z' - 'a' == 25`